# Попытка подключения по Modbus RTU протоколу к com-порту "Unknown Application"

Tags: java, com-порт, modbus

Пытаюсь подключиться из java к com-порту. Написал код, создал виртуальный порт в "Configure Virtual Serial Port Driver", установил параметры через Modbus Slave, пытаюсь подключиться из java с помощью jamod - вылетает ошибка. В чем может быть проблема ? Я в Modbus новичок.

```
java.lang.Exception: Unknown Application
at net.wimpi.modbus.net.SerialConnection.open(SerialConnection.java:102)
at ru.monitor.dgs.Main.main(Main.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusSerialTransaction.execute(ModbusSerialTransaction.java:168)
at ru.monitor.dgs.Main.main(Main.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Вот код java:

```
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusCoupler;
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusException;
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusSerialTransaction;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputRegistersRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputRegistersResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.SerialConnection;
import net.wimpi.modbus.util.SerialParameters;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    SerialConnection con = null;
    ModbusSerialTransaction trans = null;
    ReadInputRegistersRequest req = null; //the request
    ReadInputRegistersResponse res = null; //the response

    String portname = "COM3";
    int unitid = 0; //the unit identifier we will be talking to
    int ref = 0; //the reference, where to start reading from
    int count = 0; //the count of IR's to read
    int repeat = 1; //a loop for repeating the transaction

    //ModbusCoupler.createModbusCoupler(null);
    ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(1);

    SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();
    params.setPortName(portname);
    params.setBaudRate(9600);
    params.setDatabits(8);
    params.setParity("None");
    params.setStopbits(1);
    params.setEncoding("rtu");
    params.setEcho(false);

    // Открываем соединение
    con = new SerialConnection(params);
    try {
        con.open();
        System.out.println(con.getSerialPort());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // подготавливаем запрос
    req = new ReadInputRegistersRequest(ref, count);
    req.setUnitID(unitid);
    req.setHeadless();

    trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);
    trans.setRequest(req);

    //7. Execute the transaction repeat times
    int k = 0;
    do {
        try {
            trans.execute();
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        res = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
        for (int n = 0; n < res.getWordCount(); n++) {
            System.out.println("Word " + n + "=" + res.getRegisterValue(n));
        }
        k++;
    } while (k < repeat);

    con.close();
}
```

}

Вот параметры подключения к виртуальному порту 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот видно что порту установлены параметры из Modbus Slave
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видео недоступно, не помните как решили проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему.Я открывал только один порт, надо два - один для отправки запросов, другой для отправки ответов. Видимо создавал неправильно виртуальные порты, сделал по этому видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEqI8uSXBeg , все получилось. Почему то с включенной программой "Configure Virtual Serial Port Driver" вылетала ошибка "java.lang.Exception: Unknown Application", после ее отключения все удачно подключилось.